# Several loop in search result

Tags: categories, loop, search

I would like use two loops in the results after a search.

First of all, I begin the loop if there is result

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

and after a loop to display the articles belonging a category

```
<?php $cats = get_categories();

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        query_posts('cat='.$cat->cat_ID); ?>

        <h2><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></h2>

        <ul>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
            <?php endwhile;  ?>
        </ul>

        <?php } ?>
```

But it seems it display all the articles or make a infinite loop and doesn't fit with request made at the begining.

**EDIT :** In this result page, I would to organize by category. For instance, if I have four articles for the same category, it display just once the category name.

**Category_name_1**

- First article
- Second article
- Third article

**Category_name_2**

- First article

Comment: This question is very confusing. The latest edit more or less reverses what the original question appeared to be asking. Please do a better job with the explanation. I am feeling like I have been wasting my time.

Comment: You're right, it's isn't clear, but I didn't succeed to explain easily. I will write the all post soon.

Answer (score 0):

Add wp_reset_postdata(); after each loop, if you use your custom query, you should use wp_reset_query();

Comment: wp_reset_postdata() doesn't work whereas wp_reset_query() work and avoid the infinite loop. But it duplicate twice the content and doesn't fit to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer Loop uses the data in the `global` variable `$wp_query`. `query_posts` changes the data in the `global` variable `$wp_query`. Since you run `query_posts` at each iteration of the Loop, clobbering `$wp_query` every time, an infinite Loop is pretty much inevitable, along with other unwanted behavior. It is like trying to count to 100 but every time you get to a number you have to start over with some other random number. It doesn't work.

The solution is don't clobber `$wp_query` which you would do by following the rule that ought to be this site's motto: Don't use `query_posts`, ever.

Instead, create a new `WP_Query` object as in [this example from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

In your case, I am not 100% sure what you are aiming for but to show posts from all categories, this should do it:

```
$cats = get_categories();

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  $catposts = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'cat' => $cat->cat_ID,
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    )
  ); ?>

  <h2><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></h2>

  <ul><?php 
    while ($catposts->have_posts()) {
      $catposts->the_post(); ?>
      <li><?php the_title(); ?></li><?php 
    } ?>
  </ul><?php
}
```

Now, I think you might want to only show links to other posts in the same category as the current post in the outer Loop. For that you do not want `get_categories`, you want [`wp_get_post_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories)

```
if (have_posts()) { 
  while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    $cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID,array('fields' => 'all'));

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
      $catposts = new WP_Query(
        array(
          'cat' => $cat->term_id,
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
          'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
      ); ?>

      <h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2>

      <ul><?php 
        while ($catposts->have_posts()) {
          $catposts->the_post(); ?>
          <li><?php the_title(); ?></li><?php 
        } ?>
      </ul><?php
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's in the if part where category will appear, and in the while part where the differents articles of this category will appear ? It's in the $args I need to call category ?
Sorry I don't understand everything.

Comment: Yes, in the `$args` you will need to specify your category.

Comment: But when I do : `$args = array('cat' => 'cat_ID');` it returns all the articles and for each articles, the category. If I have three articles from the same category, I would to print only one time the category name.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. The category ID isn't `cat_ID`, it is `$cat->cat_ID` as you used in your own code. Why did you not do the same thing?

Comment: I will be honest, I think I didn't understand everything right now. I need to keep the `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` and replace the second loop with the WP_Query ?

Comment: @Jeremdsgn : see the edit

Comment: Okay, it sounds better now. I was looking if the `wp_get_post_categories` accept to exclude some categories ? but I didn't find anything. Moreover, with this loop, I have two categories who had been repeat twice?

Comment: A category will be repeated for each post to which is assigned.  Perhaps you should edit the question to include all the details and conditions of the problem?

Comment: I made a little update to the initial post. Don't know if it can help much.